# Logout Button with PHP Classes

Tags: javascript, php, class

Right now I'm using jquery to run a php script which isn't working, i know that php is a server side script and you can't run the script from jquery, in that case what is the best way to call a php function within a class from the browser?

This is the class where the logout function is defined

```
class Profile
{
   private function logout()
   {
       $_SESSION = array();
       session_destroy();
   }
```

This is the php page where i want to call the function upon click of the logout button

```
<?php

include_once('profileclass.php');
$user = new Profile($name, $id);

?>

<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
     <input type='button' value='logout' id='logout'>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#logout').click(function() {
          <?php $user->logout(); ?>
      }
      });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That won't work because the PHP code is evaluated before the client side can do anything. You need to use AJAX etc. for this!

Comment: Don't forget `session_start();` cuz it really won't work at all. ;-)

Comment: ya i have that in my code i just didn't copy and paste everything i forgot that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not mix PHP with Javascript, since PHP code is executed before the browser renders the html on page. Instead, use `$_POST` global variable, which will contain the data submitted to your page.

Use:

```
<?php
include_once('profileclass.php');
$user = new Profile($name, $id);
if ($_POST['logout'] == "<some_value>") {
    $user->logout();
}
?>
<html>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <input type='submit' value='<some_value>' name='logout'>
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Also, make your `logout` method `public`, so that it can be accessed outside your `Profile` class:

```
class Profile {
   public function logout() { // change is in this line
       $_SESSION = array();
       session_destroy();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, missed that while replying.. Now, added! Thank you for notifying me :)

Comment: i think the button type needs to be submit not button

Comment: I'm now getting Fatal error: Call to private method Profile::logout()

Answer (score 0):

Frontend

```
$('#logout').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:  '/logout.php', // Script where logout calls
        type: 'post'
    });
});
```

Backend (logout.php)

```
$user = new Profile();
$user->logout();
```

Comment: you forgot the parenthesis and semicolon for the click function and the , after url